# Is there any picture corpus?

Tags: data-request, language, images, corpora

By "picture corpus" I mean the picture collection each illustrating one word in the usually used vocabulary, such as words in Google 10000 English I found on GitHub.

For instance: vocabulary
[image]

source: [Youdao](http://dict.youdao.com/w/eng/vocabulary/#keyfrom=dict2.top.suggest)

I've crawled 2033 pictures for 2033 words (mostly nouns) in the aforementioned Google wordlist from Youdao, but it's not enough.

Comment: Here is the link of the Google 10000 English: https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english

Comment: So you want an image for most nouns, adjectives and verbs? What about adverbs? I also noticed there are names of people and places in the Google 10000 words file. Do you want those too? Search for "jeremy" or "tanzania".

Comment: No, I need mainly nouns. For the adjectives and verbs, only if the pictures are illustrative. But hardly can they be so, I suppose.

Comment: Acturally I use the words in the 20k file. Names and places are needed since they're popularly used if listed there.

Comment: I found another corpus: http://visualgenome.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be able to use the [International Picture Naming Project](http://crl.ucsd.edu/experiments/ipnp/1database.html) (IPNP), but I think the total pictures are way less than 10k.

[image]

Here's a link to the [query tool](http://crl.ucsd.edu/experiments/ipnp/dataquery/querymini.php).

---

You may get lucky searching through "image recognition" research websites. Here's one [compilation of online resources](http://imaging.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/methods/stimdatabases#PicturesObjects), and [a particular one](http://wiki.cnbc.cmu.edu/Objects).

Comment: Thanks. Pictures from IPNP seem too simple, but what I get via the links at the end of your answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

Wikidata has linked various concepts and lexemes to images. For lexemes and their senses there are not that many images yet. For concepts there are many, but many are proper nouns or complex concepts, e.g., "Berlin" or "Chile at the 1956 Winter Olympics"

For Wikidata lexemes a query with the Wikidata Query Service at https://query.wikidata.org may be formulated as this:

```
#defaultView:ImageGrid
SELECT ?lexeme ?lemma ?image {
  ?lexeme ontolex:sense / wdt:P18 ?image ;
          wikibase:lemma ?lemma ;
          wikibase:lexicalCategory wd:Q1084 ;  # nouns
          dct:language wd:Q9035 .  # language = Danish
}
```

Here the language is set to Danish. The result is available here: http://tinyurl.com/yb8aeks6 You can edit the query from the link in the lower left corner.

A reformulation using sense and their links to ordinary Wikidata items (concepts) looks like this with the English language:

```
#defaultView:ImageGrid
SELECT ?lexeme ?lemma ?image {
  ?lexeme ontolex:sense / wdt:P5137? / wdt:P18 ?image ;
          wikibase:lemma ?lemma ;
          wikibase:lexicalCategory wd:Q1084 ;  # nouns
          dct:language wd:Q1860 .  # language = English
}
```

A result is available here: http://tinyurl.com/ybuuy45g

Answer (score 0):

In the [VisualGenome](http://visualgenome.org/data_analysis/statistics) there are 75,729 unique objects with labels, and they provide [APIs](http://visualgenome.org/api/v0/api_endpoint_reference.html) for easy use and [a tutorial](http://visualgenome.org/api/v0/api_beginners_tutorial.html).

To get an image word pair one only needs to crop the picture and get the corresponding region.

Comment: And [Wit](https://github.com/google-research-datasets/wit) would also be helpful.